# how to trim a field with Persian text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, persian, trim

I have a column which should contain the names of cities, but some users made a mistake an entered the full address. Now I want to delete the extra part of that and just keep the first part.

For example I have:

```
  1- Paris,lab lab, shop shop, no 23
  2- London,street 1,street 2,No 11 
  3- New York,street 1,street 2,No 11
```

But what i want is :

```
 1-Paris

 2-London

 3-New York
```

but I just want Paris and I like to delete the rest. The `city` column is in Persian Language and as you might know, **Persian is written from right to left.**

Thank you for your help

Comment: What about using REVERSE, then SUBSTRING with INDEXOF and then REVERSE again?

Comment: Isn't there a way to detect the comma or any other delimiter used in fields and delete from there?

Comment: Tell me one thing, when you say your data is 1-Paris... and later you say Persian is written from right to left, then you mean you have 1-siraP in your data, is that correct?

Comment: no dear, I did not write the exact values in Persian, because i thought you wont understand it. addresses are like : تهران،خیابان 1،خیابان 2،خیابان 3 and i just want تهران

Comment: That doesn't matter how that is in Persian, my question was about order of characters. So for example you have 1-ddddddd, siraP and you expect 1-siraP

Comment: Wait, so don't have commas in Persian language? What separator should I use then?

Comment: comma in Persian is like this : ،   i don't want to reverse the values. i just want to delete what is written after the first comma

Comment: I am reversing it twice to be able to remove everything after the comma, so after reversing it twice the result won't be reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT 
LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([name]),1, CHARINDEX('٬', REVERSE('٬' + [name])) - 1)))
FROM dbo.City
```

You can create similar queries for UPDATE if you want to change the data.

To clarify:
If you have following cities in the dbo.City table:

1. London
2. New York
3. line 1, line 2, Paris

Then it returns

1. London
2. New York
3. Paris

Update your post with an example of what you expect in case I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: this query should return all the values in city column right?  after trimming them?  but it doesn't :( it just returns the old addresses written in city field

Comment: See updated post with the example. That query should leave right to left notation and remove everything in the string up to the last comma.

Comment: I Updated the question, see if you have understood the question correctly. thanks

Comment: I updated the answer with Persian comma instead of English one. Try if that helps